# Creating A React Project In such a way that it should be able to run each feature individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Want to create a react project using `create-react-app` with the following structure:

```
project-name dir
    -feature1 dir
    -feature2 dir
    -feature3 dir

 package.json
```

As It can be easily understood from the structure that each feature is going to have it's own directory.

Now the stack holders want the project in such a way that they should be able to run each feature individually in the browser.

i.e.

```
>cd feature1
feature1> npm start or yarn start
```

I dont know how to approach this situation. Few months ago I came across a similar project wherein each feature had it's own `package.json` but that project was broken was not working correctly.

So can anybody guide how can I do this? OR is it even possible to do this? using `create-react-app` or any other solution?

Comment: Not sure about your purpose, but the package.json can be initialized by run "npm init".

Comment: Take a look at Lerna JS: https://github.com/lerna/lerna